# Angularjs: Can transcluded elements "live" in the parent controller's scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like directives in the transcluded content to "live" in the directive's parent controller

ex: in the view below, I would like the binding "varInMyController" to
be bound to the variable of the same name in MyController.

I could explicitely pass variables in the directive scope:{aVar: '='},
but I want to avoid this, because the directive needs to be generic.

is this possible ?

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div my-directive>
      {{varInMyControllerScope}}
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('myDirective', [function() {
     return {
       transclude: true,
       replace: true,
       templateUrl: '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
       scope: {
         options: '='
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
     }
  }])

  angular.module('MyModule')
    .controller('myController', ['$scope'function($scope) {
      $scope.varInMyControllerScope  = "hello"
  }])
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Associated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g5qPK86DYE3UhEJLwF3A?p=preview).

The most crucial problem of your above is this line in the directive

```
templateUrl: '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
```

use `template` instead since it isn't a URL.

If this isn't a partial code, then another problem might be the initialization of your module. It should look like this from the start:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
```

Another problem is the spelling typo of your second invocation for the `angular.module()` method:

```
angular.module('MyModule');
```

It should be

```
angular.module('myModule');
```

Lastly is the comma between the array of passed in the controller function is not separated by `,`

```
 ['$scope'function($scope) {
      $scope.varInMyControllerScope  = "hello"
  }]
```

It should be

```
['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.varInMyControllerScope  = "hello"
  }]
```